# String replace with substring

Tags: c#, json, regex

I have a string as below.

```
{{"sId":"HSFJFKJ.dsfhshd","min":"AKK213AD23456","info":"text"},
{"sId":"HSFJFKJ.dsd7shd","min":["BKK213ACD23456","BKK213AB1CD23456"],"info":"text"},
{"sId":"HSFJFKJ.dsdf7shd","min":"BKK213AB1CD23456","info":"text"},
{"sId":"HSFJFKJ.dsdd7shd","min":"CKK213AB1CD23456","info":"text"}}
```

If you see the "min" value is sometimes single and sometimes repeating.
Hence I want to remove this repetition of "min" value. It has to be a single value.

So i want to parse the full string(very long string), and find if "min" has multiple values. If it has multiple value, then replace it with single value.

**Example:**

Replace:

```
"min":["BKK213AB1CD23456","BKK213AB1CD23456"]
```

With:

```
"min":"BKK213AB1CD23456"
```

Looking for any simple solution for this in C#.

Comment: do you always have square brackets for min's value even when it is single element?

Comment: Only if multiple values are there, then we have square brackets

Comment: Your format is inconsistent. You can work around duplicates, but your format needs to consistent.

Comment: Sorry, i just updated it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a straight regex solution. Any single "min" values will be left alone, while multiples will be reduced to the first value.

```
Regex.Replace(input, "\"min\":\\[(\"[A-Z\\d]+\").+?\\]", "\"min\":$1");
```

**Breakdown:**

- `\[` and `\]` match the literal brackets
- `("[A-Z\d]+")` matches a string in quotes and captures the group
- `.+?` matches everything else (lazy match) before the closing bracket
- In the replace, `$1` references the capture group

See my solution on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/EU8G6Y/1)

Answer (score 0):

Make a class as following

```
public class Data
{
    public int SId { get; set;}
    public HashSet<string> hashsetMinValues { get; set;}
    public string Info { get; set;}

    public List<Data> ReadData()
    {
        //Read you object in list of data i.e List<Data>
    }
}
```

when you are adding `min` values in the hashset, hashset will remove duplicate values by itself

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the best you can do..

```
void Main()
{
    var inputStr = @"[{'sId':'HSFJFKJ.dsfhshd','min':'AKK213AD23456','info':'text'},
    {'sId':'HSFJFKJ.dsd7shd','min':['BKK213AB1CD23456','BKK213AB1CD23456'],'info':'text'},
    {'sId':'HSFJFKJ.dsdf7shd','min':'BKK213AB1CD23456','info':'text'},
    {'sId':'HSFJFKJ.dsdd7shd','min':'CKK213AB1CD23456','info':'text'}]";

    inputStr = inputStr.Replace("'min':'","'min':['").Replace("','info'","'],'info'");

    var dest = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<test[]>(inputStr);

    var finalList = dest.Select(d => new test() { sId=d.sId,min=d.min.Distinct().ToArray(),info=d.info });

    //This will have your final string
    var output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(finalList);

}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class test
{
    public string sId { get; set; }
    public string[] min { get; set; }
    public string info { get; set; }
}
```